# Remove Apple Watch and Imessage from Cordova App

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a Cordova created project which I added ios platform.
When I upload it to the AppStore, I see that Apple Watch and iMessage are present in the Multimedia Manager ( in order to send their respective screenshots ).

How can I remove Apple Watch and iMessage from my app in AppStore ?

My App is configured only for Device Family 1,2 ( which is iPhone and Ipad ) only. When I Archive it to upload to AppStore, I must set General Device in order to do so.

Steps taken for solving this issue:
- Checked the Cordova generated workspace in Xcode, in order to remove Watchkit. Watchkit is not there.
- Checked Capabilities in Xcode. All off.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please edit your question to focus on the actual problem you have? Also, please focus on one issue per question post.

Comment: @nohillside done. I have kept the steps taken to try to solve the issue and kept what are my Xcode configurations. Thanks